# Cannot connect to ipv6 address

Tags: windows, networking, ipv6

I got public ipv6 on my android phone by my ISP. I ran a http server on that phone and checked on https://port.tools/port-checker-ipv6/ to see if it is visible, and yes it was visible. I can connect to the server from another phone, but I cannot from my Windows laptop. What might be the reason? The laptop is able to connect to other ipv6 addresses.

Comment: Are both the mobiles (eg the one running the server, and the one you used for testing) on the same mobile network? If it could be that your mobile data provider has blocked inbound HTTP/HTTPS on its border, in which case from a completely different connection (eg from your laptop) if night not be able to connect, but from a mobile on the same network it can if it doesn't need to go out and back into the network to reach the server.

Comment: @KeithLangmead Yes, both the phones have same ISP and the laptop is connected via mobile hotspot of server phone.

Comment: If the laptop is connected via a different wifi, perhaps hotspotted to the other mobile, does it work then? I wonder if your issue is a side effect of the hotspotting, since the laptop will presumably be receiving an internal IP on a different network from the mobile, so has no way to know its gateway (eg the mobile) is also the ipv6 address it's trying to reach. Also some network gear (eg at the ISP) doesn't by default allow connecting out and back in to the same place. There's a technical term for it but can't remember it offhand, but have hit it in the past.

Comment: Still doesn't work after changing hotspot. The technical term you're talking about is probably "hairpinning". That might be the issue.